# How to send a slack response that all is OK, operation_timeout error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-post, webhooks, slack-commands

I'm trying to do a slack slash command.
This command get a text in this command, than go to google sheet and lookup it. The result of lookup sent like a message to the slack to channel.
And i am in short way to finish it, but i cant to solve a problem with Slackbot message:  [failed with the error "operation_timeout"].
Found an information that the problem is in the necessary quick response to slack that POST is received "OK" (200 status code), but i cant understand how it to do.
Code below is worked but give me an operation_timeout error.

```
Function doPost(request) {
  var icao = JSON.stringify(request.parameters.text);
  var search_key = icao.substring(2, 6);
  buildReport(search_key);
}

function buildReport(search_key) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('xxxx').getRange("B3:M1900").getValues();
  var index = 6;
  var vLookupResult = vlookup(search_key, data, index);
  function vlookup(search_key, data, index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      if (data[i][0] == search_key)
        return data[i][index - 1];
  }
  var payload = {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "Location info: " + vLookupResult
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  var option = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx', option);
}
```

If i add something like that in doPost functions i get a massage from slackbot: [Request failed for https://hooks.slack.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: invalid_payload (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) ].

```
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
    var option = {
    "method": "post",
    "token" : 'XXXxxxxXXXxxxxXXX',
    "contentType": "application/json",
    };
  var response = request.parameters.response_url;
  let url = new URL (response);
```

Please help me understand what should i do with the code to have a quick response to slack and do not received "operation_timeout" error.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Start by adding a return statement to the `doPost` function. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi, Once you receive payload from /slashCommand, sent back acknowledgement. Then use the response_url to send processed data back.

Comment: thx, i modified my code in doPost function:   var response_url = request.parameters.response_url;
  var option = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": {
      "response_type": "ephemeral"
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(response_url, option);
  buildReport(request);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('');
}